# Pass state data to modal onClick Button REACT

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog

How can i pass the state data courseName:'',
                    description:'',
                    subjectAreaId:'',
                    status:'',
                    locked:'', to modal when opening it. For me to be able to edit it. Im New in react. I cant seem to pass it through on click in the button below. and setting its state in the toggle modal event.  Thanks for the help

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { withRouter, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Spinner,Modal, ModalHeader, ModalBody, ModalFooter, UncontrolledDropdown, DropdownToggle, DropdownMenu, DropdownItem, Button, ButtonGroup, Alert } from 'reactstrap';
import { CSVLink, CSVDownload } from "react-csv";
import { Panel, PanelHeader, PanelBody } from './../../components/panel/panel.jsx';
import $ from 'jquery';
import SweetAlert from 'react-bootstrap-sweetalert';
import ReactNotification from 'react-notifications-component';
import 'react-notifications-component/dist/theme.css';

class Courses extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
            this.state = {
                error: null,
                isLoaded: false,
                items: [],
                courses:[],

                //state for sweetalert
                modalDialog: false,
                modalWithoutAnimation: false,
                modalMessage: false,
                modalAlert: false,
                sweetAlertPrimary: false,
                sweetAlertInfo: false,
                sweetAlertWarning: false,
                sweetAlertSuccess: false,
                sweetAlertError: false,

                //data to display in table

                tableData: [{
                    courseName:'',
                    description:'',
                    subjectAreaId:'',
                    status:'',
                    locked:'',
                }],
                courseName:'',
                description:'',
                subjectAreaId:'',
                status:'',
                locked:'',
            }



            //binded elements


            this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
            this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
            this.handleEdit = this.handleEdit.bind(this);
            this.handleEditChange = this.handleEditChange.bind(this);
            this.handleDelete = this.handleDelete.bind(this);
            this.handletoggleClose = this.handletoggleClose.bind(this);

            this.toggleModal = this.toggleModal.bind(this);
            this.toggleSweetAlert = this.toggleSweetAlert.bind(this);
            this.addNotification = this.addNotification.bind(this);
            this.notificationDOMRef = React.createRef();
    }

    //onchange event handling post data from register department
    handleChange(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(event.target.name)
        console.log(event.target.value)
        this.setState({
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value
        });
    };

    //onchange event handling edit 
    handleEditChange(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(event.target.name)
        console.log(event.target.value)
        this.setState({
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value
        });
    };

    //handle onclick event delete
    handleDelete(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    handletoggleClose(event){

    }

    //function for notification
    addNotification(notificationType, notificationTitle, notificationMessage, notificationPosition, notificationContent) {
        if (notificationContent) {
            notificationContent = (
                <div class="widget-list widget-list-rounded inverse-mode w-100">
                    <div class="widget-list-item">
                        <div class="widget-list-media">
                            <img src="../assets/img/user/user-12.jpg" alt="" class="rounded" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="widget-list-content">
                            <h4 class="widget-list-title">Christopher Struth</h4>
                            <p class="widget-list-desc">Bank Transfer</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        }
        this.notificationDOMRef.current.addNotification({
            title: notificationTitle,
            message: notificationMessage,
            type: notificationType,
            insert: "top",
            container: notificationPosition,
            animationIn: ["animated", "fadeIn"],
            animationOut: ["animated", "fadeOut"],
            dismiss: { duration: 2000 },
            dismissable: { click: true },
            content: notificationContent
        });
    }

    //event for toggling modal
    toggleModal(name, tableData) {
        switch (name) {
            case 'modalDialog':
                this.setState({ modalDialog: !this.state.modalDialog });
                break;
            case 'modalWithoutAnimation':
                this.setState({ modalWithoutAnimation: !this.state.modalWithoutAnimation, tableData:tableData});
                break;
            case 'modalMessage':
                this.setState({ modalMessage: !this.state.modalMessage });
                break;
            case 'modalAlert':
                this.setState({ modalAlert: !this.state.modalAlert });
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    //sweetalert notification toggle
    toggleSweetAlert(name) {
        switch (name) {
            case 'primary':
                this.setState({ sweetAlertPrimary: !this.state.sweetAlertPrimary });
                break;
            case 'info':
                this.setState({ sweetAlertInfo: !this.state.sweetAlertInfo });
                break;
            case 'success':
                this.setState({ sweetAlertSuccess: !this.state.sweetAlertSuccess });
                break;
            case 'warning':
                this.setState({ sweetAlertWarning: !this.state.sweetAlertWarning });
                break;
            case 'error':
                this.setState({ sweetAlertError: !this.state.sweetAlertError });
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }


    //Use to get a new token when token expires, token expires in back end api
    refreshToken() {
        let sessionToken = sessionStorage.getItem('session');
        let sessToken = sessionToken.replace(/\"/g, "");
        axios.get('http://tfismartasp-001-site10.btempurl.com/api/Login/token/refresh', {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer' + " " + sessToken
            },
            responseType: 'json'
        }).then(response => {
            //display new token
            console.log(response.data)
            //set new token 
            let newToken = response.data;
            //set new token in session storage
            sessionStorage.setItem('session', JSON.stringify(newToken));
            window.location.reload();
        });
    }



    //fetch api for list of students
    componentDidMount() {
        //get department
        let sessionToken = sessionStorage.getItem('session');
        let sessToken = sessionToken.replace(/\"/g, "");
        axios.get('http://tfismartasp-001-site10.btempurl.com/api/Course', {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer' + " " + sessToken
            },
            responseType: 'json'
        }).then(response => {
            console.log(sessToken)
            this.setState({  
                isLoaded: true,
                courses: response.data,
                tableData: response.data });
        }, (error) => {
            console.log(error.response.status);
            const errorMessage = error.response.status;
            if (error.response.status === 401) {
                this.refreshToken();
            }
        });
    }

    async handleDelete(event, id) {
        let sessionToken = sessionStorage.getItem('session');
        let sessToken = sessionToken.replace(/\"/g, "");
        console.log(id);
        const getDelete = await fetch('http://tfismartasp-001-site10.btempurl.com/api/Department' + id, {
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer' + " " + sessToken
            },
            method: "DELETE",
        });
        this.componentDidMount();
    }



    //save data, course registration
    async handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const {
            courseName,
            description,
            subjectAreaId,
            status,
            locked
        } = this.state;
        const postData = {
            courseName,
            description,
            subjectAreaId,
            status,
            locked
        };
        //get session in session storage browser
        let sessionToken = sessionStorage.getItem('session');
        let sessToken = sessionToken.replace(/\"/g, "");

        fetch('http://tfismartasp-001-site10.btempurl.com/api/Course', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer' + " " + sessToken
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(postData),
        })
        .then(response => { 
            if(response.status === 400){
            // this.addNotification('danger', 'Danger', 'Complete Fields /  Canceled', 'top-right')
            return response.json();
            }else{
            this.addNotification('success', 'Success', 'All Data is Saved', 'top-right')
            this.componentDidMount();
            return response.json();
            }
        })
        //response error
        .then(responseerror => {
            this.addNotification('danger', 'Danger', responseerror.errorMessage, 'top-right');
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log("fetch error" + err);
        });
        this.toggleModal("modalDialog")
    }


    //Save edited data from modal, Edit Profile

    async handleEdit(event, id) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(id);
        const {
            courseName,
            description,
            subjectAreaId,
            status,
            locked
        } = this.state;
        const editData = {
            courseName:this.state.courseName,
            description:this.state.description,
            subjectAreaId:this.state.subjectAreaId,
            status:this.state.status,
            locked:this.state.locked
        };

        let sessionToken = sessionStorage.getItem('session');
        let sessToken = sessionToken.replace(/\"/g, "");

        const getEdit = await fetch('http://tfismartasp-001-site10.btempurl.com/api/Department/' + id, {
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer' + " " + sessToken
            },
            method: "PUT",
            body: JSON.stringify(editData),
        });

        this.componentDidMount();

        console.log(JSON.stringify(editData));

    }

    render() {

        //inline css test
        var well={
            // boxShadow: "1px 5px 8px #888888",
            border: "1px solid #e6e6e6",
            height:215,
            color: 'white',
            textDecoration: "none",
            borderRadius: 4
            }
        var ddown={
            fontSize: 24,
            backgroundColor: "transparent",
            border: 0,
            border:"transparent",
            color:"black"
        }

        //check session
        let user = localStorage.getItem('session');
        if (user) {
            console.log('Valid session Student');
        } else {
            console.log('Not valid session');
            this.props.history.push('/user/login-v2');
        }

        //use to delcare table data to this.state
        const { tableData, error, isLoaded, courses, selectedData } = this.state;

        //check data, if 1 then display courses
        if (error) {
            return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
          } else if (!isLoaded) {
            return <div className="container" style={{textAlign:'center',marginTop:400}}>
            <Spinner type="grow" color="primary" />
            <Spinner type="grow" color="secondary" />
            <Spinner type="grow" color="success" />
            <Spinner type="grow" color="danger" />
            <Spinner type="grow" color="warning" />
            <Spinner type="grow" color="info" />
            <Spinner type="grow" color="light" />
            <Spinner type="grow" color="dark" />
          </div>;
          } else {
             //jquery function for search courses using cards
            $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
            let value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
            // ('div[data-role="coursescard"]')_
            $('div[data-role="coursescard"]').filter(function() {
              $(this).delay(3000).toggle($(this).find('h4').text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
            });
          });
        return (
            <div>

                {/* modal for course editing*/}
                <Modal isOpen={this.state.modalWithoutAnimation} fade={false} toggle={() => this.toggleModal("modalWithoutAnimation")}>
                    <ModalHeader toggle={() => this.toggleModal("modalWithoutAnimation")}>
                        Edit Department
                    </ModalHeader>
                    <form className="margin-bottom-0" onSubmit={this.handleEdit}>
                        <ModalBody>
                        <h3><label className="control-label">Course Information </label></h3>
                            <div className="row row-space-10">
                                <div className="col-md-4 m-b-15">
                                    <label className="control-label">Course Name <span className="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                    <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Course Name" name="courseName" defaultValue={this.state.courseName} onChange={this.handleChange} required="" />
                                </div>
                                <div className="col-md-4 m-b-15">
                                    <label className="control-label">Description <span className="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                    <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Description" name="description" defaultValue={this.state.description} onChange={this.handleChange} required="" />
                                </div>

                                <div className="col-md-4 m-b-15">
                                    <label className="control-label">Subject Area </label>
                                    <select className="form-control" name="subjectAreaId" defaultValue={this.state.subjectAreaId} onChange={this.handleChange}>
                                        <option defaultValue={1}>Science</option>
                                        <option defaultValue={2}>English</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>

                                <div className="col-md-4 m-b-15">
                                    <label className="control-label">Status </label>
                                    <select className="form-control" name="status" defaultValue={this.state.status} onChange={this.handleChange}>

                                        <option defaultValue={true}>Active</option>
                                        <option defaultValue={false}>Inactive</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>

                                <div className="col-md-4 m-b-15">
                                    <label className="control-label">Lock Status </label>
                                    <select className="form-control" name="locked" defaultValue={this.state.locked} onChange={this.handleChange}>

                                        <option defaultValue={true}>Locked</option>
                                        <option defaultValue={false}>Not Locked</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </ModalBody>
                        <ModalFooter>
                            <button 
                                onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
                                onClick={(e) => {
                                this.handleEdit(e, this.state.id)
                                this.toggleModal("modalWithoutAnimation")
                            }} className="btn btn-sm btn-success">Save Edit</button>
                            <button
                                className="btn btn-white btn-sm"
                                onClick={() => this.toggleModal("modalWithoutAnimation")} >
                                Close
                        </button>
                        </ModalFooter>
                    </form>
                </Modal>



                <Panel>

                    <PanelHeader>
                        Course List |  <button className="btn btn-xs btn-icon btn-circle btn-default" onClick={() => {

                            this.toggleModal("modalDialog");
                        }}><i className="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
                    </PanelHeader>


                    <ReactNotification ref={this.notificationDOMRef} />
                        {/* Search Box for courses */}
                        <div className="form-group" style={{padding: 5}}>
                            <input type="text" className="form-control" id="myInput" name="myInput" placeholder="Enter keyword"></input>
                        </div>

                        <div className="row" style={{paddingLeft:5, paddingRight:5}}>
                            {courses.map(course => (
                                <div className="col-md-3" key={course.id} data-role="coursescard">
                                    <div className='widget-card widget-card-rounded m-b-20' style={well}  >
                                    {/* style={{backgroundImage: 'url(/assets/img/login-bg/login-bg-15.jpg)'}} */}
                                        <div className="widget-card-cover"></div>
                                        <div className="widget-card-content">
                                            <h5 className='f-s-12 text-white-transparent-7 text-black-transparent-7'><b>
                                            {/* <UncontrolledDropdown className="pull-right" style={{ padding: 0 + '!important' }}>
                                                <DropdownToggle className="" style={ddown}>
                                                    <i className="ion ion-md-more"></i>
                                                </DropdownToggle>
                                                <DropdownMenu right>
                                                    <DropdownItem onClick={() => {
                                                    this.toggleModal("modalWithoutAnimation");
                                                }}><i className="ion ion-md-create fa-lg"></i> Edit</DropdownItem>
                                                <DropdownItem>
                                                    <a onClick={() => {
                                                    this.toggleSweetAlert('error')
                                                }}
                                                ><i className="ion ion-ios-trash fa-lg"></i> Delete</a></DropdownItem>

                                                </DropdownMenu>

                                            </UncontrolledDropdown> */}

                                            <button className="btn btn-danger btn-icon btn-circle btn-md m-r-2 float-right" onClick={() => {
                                                    this.toggleSweetAlert('error')
                                                }} >

                                                <i className="fa fa-times"></i>
                                            </button>

                                            <button className="btn btn-info btn-icon btn-circle btn-md m-r-2 float-right" 
                                            onClick={() => {
                                                this.toggleModal("modalWithoutAnimation",tableData)

                                                }}>
                                            <i className="fa fa-edit"></i></button>

                                            </b></h5>

                                                <h4 className="m-b-10"><b>
                                                    <Link to={{pathname: '/coursemodule/'+ course.id,
                                                       state: {
                                                           courseid:course.id,
                                                           coursename:course.courseName
                                                        }
                                                    }} style={{textDecoration:'none', color:'black' }}
                                                    >{course.courseName}</Link> 
                                                </b></h4>
                                            {/* <i className="fa fa-heartbeat fa-5x text-pink"></i> */}
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="widget-card-content bottom">
                                            <b className={(this.state.darkTheme ? 'text-white-transparent-7 ' : 'text-black-transparent-7 ')}></b>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    {(this.state.sweetAlertError &&
                                                    <SweetAlert danger showCancel
                                                        confirmBtnText="Yes, delete it!"
                                                        confirmBtnBsStyle="danger"
                                                        cancelBtnBsStyle="default"
                                                        title="Are you sure?"
                                                        onConfirm={(e) => {
                                                            this.toggleSweetAlert('error')
                                                            this.handleDelete(e, course.id)
                                                        }}
                                                        onCancel={() => this.toggleSweetAlert('error')}
                                                    >
                                                        You will not be able to recover this imaginary file!
                                                    </SweetAlert>
                                                )}
                                </div>

                            ))}
                        </div> 

                        {/* end row */}

                </div>

            );
        }
    }
}

export default withRouter(Courses);
```

Comment: If all this code belongs to the same HOC which has access to fields(courseName:, description:', subjectAreaId, ...) in state/props - then the modal component will have access to the same props/state.
Please do share the full code .

Comment: @informer edited already hope you can help me. cant seem to pass the id to modal or any data